# IE8 "Access is denied" error on refreshing the page in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, access-denied, scorm2004

In my LMS I have a iframe and to play a SCORM course I set the source of the iframe with the content's .htm file.
It works fine in all browsers except IE8.
When I try to refresh the page in IE8 the debugger reports "Access is denied" and it points to this JS code fragement :   _*flash*_removeCallback(document.getElementById(""), "");

Tried googling but couldn't find a way to fix it.
If I am correct this is because the content is created using adobe captivate.

[For sample content](http://www.jsheducation.com/vledownloads.html)

Any help would be grateful.